# GLSL textureCube fails

Tags: c#, opengl, shader, textures, fragment-shader

I have a fairly simple fragmentshader that does not work. It appears to have something to do with the textureCube method.

This is the fragment shader:

```
in vec3 ReflectDir;
in vec3 RefractDir;

uniform samplerCube CubeMapTex;
uniform bool DrawSkyBox;

uniform float MaterialReflectionFactor;

void main()
{
    // Access the cube map texture
    vec4 reflectColor = textureCube(CubeMapTex, ReflectDir);
    vec4 refractColor = textureCube(CubeMapTex, RefractDir);

    if( DrawSkyBox )
    {
        gl_FragColor = reflectColor;
        gl_FragColor = vec4(ReflectDir, 1); //This line
    }
    else
        gl_FragColor = vec4(1,0,0,1);
}
```

ReflectDir and RefractDir come from a vertex shader, but that seems to be in order.

If I comment the second line in the if statement the whole screen is black (incliding the teapot), otherwise it looks like this (ReflectDir seems ok):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2zdj.png

Also the cubemap is rendered properly (well the images orders are bad). This is how the scene looks like without the shader program:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QK5S3.jpg

Aditional info:

1. the texture is loaded with GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP on active texture TEXTURE0
2. uniform CubeMapTex is set to 0
3. DrawSkyBox is set to true when drawing the skybox, false after that
4. I used SharpGL

Comment: Where's your `#version` directive?

Comment: Well I commented that...because I was getting compilation errors. ERROR: 1:1: error(#307) Profile 'in' is not supported
ERROR: 1:1: error(#76) Syntax error unexpected tokens following #version. Somehow it thinks the next instruction is part of the #version.

Comment: Well I finaly found out what was the problem. SharpGL was reading my shader files badly. Did an update of SharpGL and now the #version directive works and along with it the whole shader. Big thanks to genpfault.